# What is the established way to export a cmake project with external dependencies?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project that I am building with Cmake. It has the following directory structure:

```
Project
|
 CMakeLists.txt
 src
 |
  MyLib.h
 |
  MyLib.cpp
 |
  CMakeLists.txt
|
 third_party
 |
  abseil-cpp
```

Since [abseil-cpp](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp) is a third-party dependency that builds with Cmake, I add it as a subdirectory in my top level CMakeLists.txt.
The src folder gets similarly added as a subdirectory in my top level CMakeLists.txt. Something like:

```
# Contents of Project/CMakeLists.txt
# Usual CMake boiler plate here.
add_subdirectory(third_party/abseil-cpp)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

My src folder CMakeLists.txt creates a single library that depends on one of the library targets made by abseil-cpp. This dependency is expressed with target_link_library. My CMakeLists.txt file in the src directory looks something like:

```
# Contents of Project/src/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(MyLib STATIC
MyLib.cpp

MyLib.h)
target_link_library(MyLib absl::base absl::optional)
```

I was following the Cmake [tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/guide/importing-exporting/index.html) to see how I could export my project as a Cmake project that other Cmake projects could import and just get MyLib (and it's dependencies) as a Cmake target in their project. The tutorial was pretty clear on how to make this happen and have CMake files created via install that another Cmake project could import via `find_package()`.

This works great as long as every dependency of MyLib is also added to the export set that I make for MyLib. However, since the abseil libraries are being built in another subdirectory by a CMakeLists.txt file that I would rather not touch, it wasn't clear to me how I would export the transitive list of dependencies along with MyLib. In the case of `absl::base` I tried exporting `abseil_base` (absl::base is an alias of abseil_base), but Cmake complained that I could not export a target that was not being built in the directory I was trying to export it from.
Is there an established way for me to export my library as a Cmake target, with the transitive set of external dependencies (like the abseil libraries) so that an importing Cmake project could add dependencies with a simple `target_link_library(external_executable MyLib::MyLib)` or similar and it would pull the transitive dependencies of MyLib too?

Comment: I think `find_package()` is the most portable way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that instead of adding it as a subdirectory, install and use it through `find_package`. [Looks like](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/issues/111) the `find_package` support was implemented.

In your CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(absl REQUIRED)

target_link_library(MyLib PUBLIC absl::base absl::optional)
```

Notice the `PUBLIC`, it is important.

Then define your dependencies using the [find_dependency](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.html) macro in your package configuration file. The [tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/guide/importing-exporting/index.html) that you were following explains how to do that.

It should look something like this:

```
@PACKAGE_INIT@

include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)
find_dependency(absl REQUIRED)

include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/MyLibTargets.cmake)
```